# MySQL with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017

I need to work with Entity Framework with MySQL database and Visual Studio 2017.

Please find the below image for my setup
[image: Setup]

### **Scenarios and Steps:**

1. Create Console App in Visual Studio 2017
2. From ServerExplorer i add new connection with MySQL Database (MySQL Data Provider) and it got sucess
3. Now added the following nuget packages for connecting MySQL along with EF

> EntityFramework 6.2.0
>
> MySql.Data.EntityFramework 8.0.11

So it installed all dependencies and the packages are follows;
[image: Package Configuration]

Here is my app.config
[image: app config]

4. Add New 'ADO.NET Entity Data Model' item and selected 'EF Designer from Database'
5. Gave connection information and select next.

***Here one Dialogue box came with Entity Framework 6.x option and suddenly closed***

Please help me to solve the issue

### **Others Findings:**

Based on some forums and articles, i verified the Visual Studio Private Assemblies folder and found the following libraries

**Path :** C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies

**Files:**

MySql.Data, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, MySql.Web (All these libraries have version 6.9.8.0)

I deleted these files and copied new files with version 8.0.11 into this folder. New files are;

MySql.Data, MySql.Data.EntityFramework, MySql.Web (All these have 8.0.11) and Google.Protobuf

1. Now i close and open visual studio again and open same solution
2. When i try to add new connection from server explorer i got he following error
   [image: Error1]

But i can continue to give connection details after pressed ok in the error dialogue. Here after fill the connection details and click ok i got the following error
[image]

**Here i confused why visual studio again check for 6.9.8. So my sql connector 8.0.11 not support in visual studio 2017?**

**If i continue to add 'Ado.net Entity Data Model' item, connection screen closed unexpectedly**

Can anyone help to solve these issue and use mysql in visual studio 2017

Comment: "Here one Dialogue box came with Entity Framework 6.x option and suddenly closed" sounds exactly like this known bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=89338 Apparently it was fixed in 6.10.7; I don't know for sure but it seems plausible that the fix either didn't make it into 8.0.11, or was regressed in that release. Since this is almost certainly a Connector/NET bug, you should identify the minimum steps to reproduce and file a bug report at https://bugs.mysql.com/